# How to run Mask_RCNN model in android studio using java or C++

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, deep-learning

I am trying use **Mask_RCNN in android**. So, written its code. But Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(MODEL_WEIGHTS, TEXT_GRAPH) function is **not able to open the model weights and text graph file**. Seems like they app is not able to find the path of files stored.
I have inserted these files(Text_Graph and Model_Weights) in java folder where mainactivity.java file is present. But it shows same error as mentioned below.
I also tried adding these files to res folder and assets folder but could not parse the model weight path to the function Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(MODEL_WEIGHTS, TEXT_GRAPH) because its arguments are of String type. But assetmanager returns input stream.
I am using opencv 3.4.10 and android studio 4.0.

**Also please help me in drawing contours over image in java. If anyone knows how to run it in android using Model in C++ then please suggest.** As I have already tried it in that also but was getting build error of undefined reference to **'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v4::Net::~Net()'**
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

On running the app it is giving exception of : ****

> Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception:
> OpenCV(3.4.10)
> /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_io.cpp:1132:
> error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open
> "./frozen_inference_graph.pb" in function 'bool
> cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(const char*,
> google::protobuf::Message*)'
> ]

---

> at org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow_0(Native Method)
> at org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(Dnn.java:659)
> at com.example.imagecompressor.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:189)(Error
> at this line : Net net = Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(MODEL_WEIGHTS,
> TEXT_GRAPH);)
> at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)

Source code is given below:

Mainactivity.java

```java
final String TEXT_GRAPH = "./mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.pbtxt";
final String MODEL_WEIGHTS = "./frozen_inference_graph.pb";
final String CLASSES_FILE ="./mscoco_labels";
Mat tmp = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CV_8UC1);
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, tmp);
Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(img_path);
image=tmp;
Size size = image.size();
int cols = image.cols();
int rows = image.rows();
double h = size.height;
double w = size.width;
int hh = (int)size.height;
int ww = (int)size.width;
if(!image.empty()) {
    Mat blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0, new Size(w, h), new Scalar(0), true, false);
    // Load the network
    Net net = Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(MODEL_WEIGHTS, TEXT_GRAPH);
    net.setPreferableBackend(Dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV);
    net.setPreferableTarget(Dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU);
    net.setInput(blob);
    ArrayList<String> outputlayers = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Mat> outputMats = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    outputlayers.add("detection_out_final");
    outputlayers.add("detection_masks");
    net.forward(outputMats, outputlayers);
    Mat numClasses = outputMats.get(0);
    Mat numMasks = outputMats.get(1);
    numClasses = numClasses.reshape(1, (int) numClasses.total() / 7);
    for (int i = 0; i < numClasses.rows(); ++i) {
          double confidence = numClasses.get(i, 2)[0];
          //System.out.println(confidence);
          // Mat objectMask=outputMats.get(i);
          if (confidence > 0.5) {
               int classId = (int) numClasses.get(i, 1)[0];
               String label = classes.get(classId) + ": " + confidence;
               System.out.println(label);
               int left = (int) (numClasses.get(i, 3)[0] * cols);
               int top = (int) (numClasses.get(i, 4)[0] * rows);
               int right = (int) (numClasses.get(i, 5)[0] * cols);
               int bottom = (int) (numClasses.get(i, 6)[0] * rows);
               System.out.println(left + " " + top + " " + right + " " + bottom);
               left = max(0, min(left, cols - 1));
               top = max(0, min(top, rows - 1));
               right = max(0, min(right, cols - 1));
               bottom = max(0, min(bottom, rows - 1));
               final Rect box = new Rect(left, top, right - left + 1, bottom - top + 1);
      //Mat objectMask(numMasks.rows(), numMasks.size[3],CV_32F, numMasks.ptr<float>(i,classId));
               // Mat obj();
               Mat objectMask = new Mat(numMasks.rows(), numMasks.cols(), CV_32F);
 rectangle(image, new Point(box.x, box.y), new Point(box.x + box.width, box.y + box.height), new Scalar(255, 178, 50), 3);
               /* String lab = format("%.2f", confidence);
               if (!classes.isEmpty()){
                  //CV_Assert(classId < (int)classes.size());
                  if(classId<(int)classes.size()) {
                      lab = classes.get(classId) + ":" + lab;
                   }
                }*/
                Scalar color = new Scalar(rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256));
                double maskThreshold = 0.3;
                // Resize the mask, threshold, color and apply it on the image
                resize(objectMask, objectMask, new Size(box.width, box.height));
                Imgproc.threshold(objectMask, objectMask, 255 * maskThreshold, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
                // Mat mask = (objectMask > maskThreshold);
                Mat ili = new Mat();
                multiply(image, new Scalar(0.7), ili);
                Mat coloredRoi = new Mat();
                add(ili, new Scalar(0.3).mul(color), coloredRoi);
                coloredRoi.convertTo(coloredRoi, CV_8UC3);
                List<MatOfPoint> contours = null;
                Mat hierarchy = null;
                objectMask.convertTo(objectMask, CV_8U);
                findContours(objectMask, contours, hierarchy, RETR_CCOMP,CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
                drawContours(coloredRoi, contours, -1, color, 5, LINE_8, hierarchy, 100);
                coloredRoi.copyTo(image, objectMask);
          }
          Mat detectedFrame = new Mat();
          image.convertTo(detectedFrame, CV_8U);
          Imgcodecs.imwrite("outputFile.jpg", detectedFrame);

    }

}
```